# A comprehensive list of conceptual metaphors

Tags: computational-linguistics, dictionary

Is there a comprehensive list of [conceptual metaphors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_metaphor)? (Either man-made, crowdsourced or based on data-mining / corpora analysis.)

By a conceptual metaphor I mean a relation in the spirit of George Lakoff and Mark Johnson’s  "Metaphors We Live By", e.g. [Time is Something Moving Toward You](http://cogsci.berkeley.edu/lakoff/metaphors/Time_Is_Something_Moving_Toward_You.html):

> When Tuesday comes... 
>   Three O'clock is approaching. 
>   Thursday passed without incident. 
>   The witching hour is near.

The only dictionary I am aware of is http://cogsci.berkeley.edu/lakoff/ (only for English, only 207 metaphors).

EDIT:

The previous link is dead. Try mirrors:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20121015142744/http://cogsci.berkeley.edu/lakoff
- http://www.lang.osaka-u.ac.jp/~sugimoto/MasterMetaphorList/

Comment: I think this question could use some clarification. Lists are not the best thing on the SE sites, but if you could narrow it so to make this list very scoped, I may keep it.

Comment: Here 'a list' is a single object (i.e. I don't expect people to write metaphors by hand, just to point to a list). I can use 'dictionary' but I don't know if it is the best word. I can narrow it to English, if it is beneficial.

Comment: did you actually find an answer to your question? I am looking for a comprehensive list as well..

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: The link to the Conceptual Metaphor Home Page (http://cogsci.berkeley.edu/lakoff/) is no longer valid. However, the following is a mirror/copy of it: http://www.lang.osaka-u.ac.jp/~sugimoto/MasterMetaphorList/.

Comment: In many ways, [Framenet](https://framenet.icsi.berkeley.edu/fndrupal/) is the successor of the Conceptual Metaphor effort.

Answer (score 1):

No. The only one I'm aware of is the list you mention. The reason is that relatively few people in linguistics actually still use the X IS Y format (mostly you find it in relatively superficial treatments). Most people see metaphor as much more complex and having a single list would simply lead to proliferation of metaphors like "ENVIRONMENTAL CLEANLINESS IS EU NATIONALISM" (made up example). So I think if we brought together a list of metaphor thus identified in the literature, we'd have a rather embarrassing mixture of various agendas. It would be an interesting project for someone, though. I once started compiling a list of metaphors used in education by people who were inspired by Lakoff and Johnson but didn't get very far.

Answer (score 1):

No. They gave up on the X IS Y form. This form is also called Mathematical Mapping and has a few shortcomings. I have extracted a few words from Metaphors We Live By, from the Afterword:

> However, the Mathematical Mapping metaphor proved to be inadequate in an important respect. Mathematical mappings do not create target entities, while conceptual metaphors often do. For example, time doesn't necessarily have a use and isn't necessarily resource. Many people in cultures around the world simply live their lives without being concerned about whether they are using their time efficiently. However, other cultures conceptualize time metaphorically as if it were a limited resource. The Time Is Money metaphor imposes on the time domain in various aspects of resources. In doing so, it adds elements to the time domain, creating a new understanding of time.